# Error when writing Parameterized constructor for class with vector of objects

Tags: c++, stl

I am getting the error "" when trying to writing parameterized constructor for the B class. B class holds a vector of A class objects. Kindly help me with this issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define NUMBER 10
class A
{
    int x;

public:
    A(int a) : x(a) {}
};

class B
{
    std::vector<A> vec[NUMBER];
public:
    B();
};

B::B() : vec(NUMBER, A(10)) {}

int main()
{
    B b;
    return 0;
}
```

Error occurring while compiling:

```
check.cxx: In constructor ‘B::B()’:
check.cxx:20:10: error: expression list treated as compound expression in mem-initializer [-fpermissive]
   20 | B::B() : vec(NUMBER, A(10)) {}
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
check.cxx:20:10: error: invalid initializer for array member ‘std::vector<A> B::vec [10]’
```

Also, help me with writing default and copy constructors ??

Comment: `std::vector<A> vec[NUMBER];` this is not how you declare a vector

Comment: Replace it with `std::vector<A> vec = std::vector<A>(NUMBER);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `std::vector<A> vec[NUMBER];` defines an **array** of size `NUMBER` with elements of type `vector<A>`.

To solve this either replace `std::vector<A> vec[NUMBER];` with just `std::vector<A>;` or with `std::vector<A> vec = std::vector<A>(NUMBER);` as shown below:

##### Method 1

Here we replace `std::vector<A> vec[NUMBER];` with:

```
class B
{
    std::vector<A> vec; // no need to use NUMBER here
public:
    B();
};
```

Note the default constructor initialized the vector member so there is no need to do it in the in-class initializer(as shown above).

---

##### Method 2

Here we use **in-class initialzer**.

```
class B
{
    std::vector<A> vec = std::vector<A>(NUMBER);  //corrected syntax
public:
    B();
};
```

[working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bsnsqPdKP)

Comment: Working demo compilation fails because no default constructor is available in class A :)

Comment: @Pisers Sure, but that is not the error anymore that you posted initially, but a different question.